# clang: error: no such file or directory: '/trunk/Source/Services... Error

Tags: search, path, header, clang

i got this error:

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/trunk/Source/Services/YouTube/Generated/GTLYouTube_Sources.m'
clang: error: no input files.

i had added the GTLYouTube_Sources.m in my project and set the Header Search Path for this file in Build Setting of xcode. But then also get the same error.
What is the issue here??

Answer (score 0):

In here "GTLYouTube_Sources.m" whether there？ If you do not have to add it.
[image]

Comment: thanx for your answer... i had just passed the path of GTLYouTube_Sources.m to **Header Search path** and then clean and Build the project. And Solved the issue.